# evaluating a double integral over a region

Tags: calculus, integration

In evaluating a double integral over a region D, a sum of iterated integrals was obtained as follows: [image]

Sketch the region D and express the double integral as an iterated integral with reversed order of integration

[image]

I already found a and b which are 0 and 3, I am reallt confussed about g2(x) and g1(x)

Comment: Did you sketch the region $D$?  What are the boundaries like?

Answer (score 1):

you may need to draw the graph of the region

take variable from outside to inside, first we check y

when y is fixed in [0, 8], x is in [0, 3y/8]

when y is fixed in [8, 11], x is in [0, 11-y]

then we could draw the graph:

[image]

then you can specify a, b, g1 and g2 by first fix x, then check the value of y.

Comment: could you be more specific

Comment: as we can see from the graph, x is from 0 to 3, for a fixed x, y is from 8x/3 to 11-x, so the integral=$\int_0^3\int_{8x/3}^{11-x}f(x,y)dydx$

Comment: Does not seem to work for f(x,y) = 2 both the original integral and your integral seem to give different results

Comment: both are 33 accrodding to what I computed by hand and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%5B2%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C3%7D%2C+%7By%2C8x%2F3%2C11-x%7D%5D

Comment: I screwed up .  I input 3x/8 that is why, I am sorry

Comment: Makes sense yours is better I took the traditional approach

Comment: I kind of made it look like the original split

Comment: Now I wonder why, you had intially put 3x/8 which you changed later to 8x/3.  You must be sorry!!!! - -)

Comment: it's typo, it's easy to mix up x and y, I changed just after I posted, and what you saw is 3x/8 just the time as I posted. I wonder where to see the edit history and the timestamp. If it makes any trouble to you, then I am sorry.

Comment: I was just joking.. No worries

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

$$\int_0^3\int_{0}^{11-x} f(x,y)dydx - \int_0^3\int_0^{8x/3} f(x,y)dydx$$

Let us take an example of f(x,y) = 2

Then evaluating the result in Wolfram Alpha:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E3%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B11-x%7D+2dydx+-+%5Cint_0%5E3%5Cint_0%5E%7B8x%2F3%7D+2dydx

At the same time, evaluating the original dxdy integral with f(x,y) = 2 should yield the same result:

Here is te result from Wolfram Alpha
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E8%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B3y%2F8%7D+2dxdy+%2B+%5Cint_8%5E%7B11%7D%5Cint_0%5E%7B11-y%7D+2dxdy